# Image Description

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/3V6MM/

Please tell me how can I write common style for class="property-title" to display the property name under the image.

Please guide me.

Images are placed like below[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this layout. Also note that ids should be unique. You are using image-thumb multiple times.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9C72X/

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="image-thumb">
    <img src="http://www.javeacasas.com/images/javea-property.jpg">
    <p class="property-title">Land for Sale</p>
    </div>

    <div class="image-thumb">
    <img src="http://in.all.biz/img/in/service_catalog/15784.jpeg">
    <p class="property-title">Sale at Mura, Puttur</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* <-- update to solve multiline text */
    width: 200px;
}

.image-thumb img { 
    width: 100%; 
}

.property-title {
    text-align: center;   
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Check the updated fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/9C72X/1/ , I am facing the following issue. when property title becomes 2 lines the layout will be misaligned

Comment: You can solve that by adding `vertical-align: top` to `image-thumb`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think you need to absolutely position the caption.

You might also consider using different mark-up.

```
<figure class="image-thumb">
    <img class="imgthumg">
    <figcaption class="property-title">
        image title
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

try this, the float left is causing your image-thumb container to collapse.

```
.img-thumb {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
    word-spacing: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.imgthumb {
    width:230px;
    height:161px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #909090;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.property-title {
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    font-size: 8pt;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 236px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I added image for better understanding, Please check the question again

Answer (score 0):

Replace these css classes with the below one :

```
 #image-thumb
 {
 padding-left: 5px;
 word-spacing: 10px;
 float:left;
 }

 .imgthumb
 {
  width:230px;
  height:161px;

  position:relative;
  background:#FFF;
  border:1px solid #909090;
  margin-left:10px;

  }

 .property-title
 {

font-family: 'Verdana';
font-size: 8pt;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 0;
position: relative;
width: 236px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abhinavpratap/3V6MM/4/